# Using AWS sns after custom cognito pool login

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sns, amazon-cognito

Im trying to integrate AWS Cognito pool sign-in/sign-up with Cognito  Federated Identities and SNS.

I check this project demo and start from here https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/AmazonCognitoYourUserPoolsDemo

when everything works ok, i download the Android project that Mobile hub generate, i check the project integrations with facebook(im going to use custom method with cognito, no fb) to understand the process. I didn't take the "new provider" path. I ended up LOGIN like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCreate");

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    //AWSMobileClient.initializeMobileClientIfNecessary(getApplicationContext());

    final Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            // Initialize cognito.
            SignInCognito.init(getApplicationContext());

            // Check if the user was already logged
            CognitoUser user = SignInCognito.getPool().getCurrentUser();
            username = user.getUserId();
            if(username != null) {
                SignInCognito.setUser(username);
                user.getSessionInBackground(authenticationHandler);
            }else{
                goSignIn();
            }

            // Wait for the splash timeout.
            try {
                Thread.sleep(SPLASH_DISPLAY_DURATION);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { }

            // Expire the splash page delay.
            timeoutLatch.countDown();
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}

AuthenticationHandler authenticationHandler = new AuthenticationHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(CognitoUserSession cognitoUserSession) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "authenticationHandler onSuccess");

        SignInCognito.setCurrSession(cognitoUserSession);

        String idToken = cognitoUserSession.getIdToken().getJWTToken();
        final Map<String, String> logins = new HashMap<String, String>();
        logins.put(
                "cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/"+ AWSConfiguration.AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID,
                idToken);

        (new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                        getApplicationContext(),
                        AWSConfiguration.AMAZON_COGNITO_IDENTITY_POOL_ID, // Identity Pool ID
                        Regions.US_EAST_1 // Region
                );

                credentialsProvider.setLogins(logins);
                credentialsProvider.refresh();

                Log.e("identity id", credentialsProvider.getIdentityId());

            }
        })).start();

        // User is authenticated
        goMain();

    }
}
```

When i execute this process i successfully have the user logged and is registered on Federated Identities.

I don't know how to continue with the push notification registration, the logs keeps telling me that im not authorized to use the PushManager and failed to register push notifications.

Also i don't know if i take the wrong path not implementing like CustomSignInProvider using for example the FacebookSignInProvider, because my problem is always with the SignInManager that im not using of course because i merge the login code from the github that i paste first.

Hope someone can take me to the correct path, and if there is a example code/repo to check would be good.

thx

Comment: If you are not authorized to do something, I suggest you check the permissions of the IAM role associated with the Cognito pool.

Comment: If you can provide a stack trace and an exact error message that would be helpful.